# Table needs restore after even opening and saving XLXS without changes

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, openpyxl

I have this simple excel file with simple table:

[image: Excel file]

Once I open it with `python openpyxl` and save it after I change headers value I get error that table was damaged.

I use `logging` for information output, `string` for list of uppercase letters, `tkinter` for `askopenfilename`, `openpyxl` for working with excel. I first intented to use `pandas` for working with excel data but since I want to keep tables and charts in the future which will be created inside Excel I did not have much options.

My code is as follows:

```
class TCA:
    def __init__(self):
        self.path = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=[("Excel files", "*.xlsx; *.xls")], initialdir='.\\')
        self.wb: pxl.Workbook = pxl.load_workbook(self.path, read_only=False)
        self.ws = None

        self.header_names = ['Project', 'TC_all', 'TC_manual', 'TC_automated', 'TC_automateable', 'TC_3rd', 'Ratio']
        self.header_order = {
            'Project': -1,
            'TC_all': -1,
            'TC_manual': -1,
            'TC_automated': -1,
            'TC_automateable': -1,
            'TC_3rd': -1,
            'Ratio': -1
        }
        self.empty_spaces = list(string.ascii_uppercase[:7])

    def load_header_order(self):
        for header in self.header_names:
            for letter in string.ascii_uppercase:
                if header == self.ws[f'{letter}1'].value:
                    self.header_order[header] = letter
                    self.empty_spaces.remove(letter)

        for key, value in self.header_order.items():
            if value == -1:
                self.insert_missing_header(key)

    def insert_missing_header(self, header):
        logging.info(f'There is missing header {header}')
        logging.info(f'Insert in progress')
        self.ws[f'{self.empty_spaces[0]}1'] = f'{header}'
        logging.info(f'Header {header} was inserted into {self.empty_spaces[0]}1')
        self.empty_spaces.__delitem__(0)

    def check_wb(self):
        return 'Preview' in self.wb.sheetnames

    def load_project_list(self):
        self.ws = self.wb['Preview']
        self.load_header_order()

    def exit(self):
        self.wb.save(self.path)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    tca = TCA()

    if not tca.check_wb():
        messagebox.showerror('Crucial error!', 'There is no sheet named "Preview"!\n'
                                               'Due to this exception script cannot proceed!\n'
                                               'If you have renamed the sheet please rename it back...')
        exit(-1)

    tca.load_project_list()
    tca.exit()
```

I have tested it many times, if excel file is simple (without talbe) code works. If I change text to table with headers it works. But once I change the header value the error occurs.

Comment: There must be something else happening that you're not showing. Tested your code and there is no effect on the Excel file

Comment: Or maybe the excel file is broken fully. Maybe I should try to redo the excel

Comment: @DarkKnight please check edit/update i just made.

Comment: You'll need to edit the table definition as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just located the issue and fixed it! The issue is that `tables` has their own `column.name` for the `headings` as well as `worksheet` has its own `call.value`.

I simply had to change `table.tableColumns[columnIndex].name` and `ws[cellIndex].value` as well.

Here is the result:

```
class TCA:
    def __init__(self):
        self.path = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=[("Excel files", "*.xlsx; *.xls")], initialdir='.\\')
        self.wb: pxl.Workbook = pxl.load_workbook(self.path, read_only=False)
        self.ws = None
        self.table = None

        self.header_names = ['Project', 'TC_all', 'TC_manual', 'TC_automated', 'TC_automateable', 'TC_3rd', 'Ratio']
        self.header_order = {
            'Project': -1,
            'TC_all': -1,
            'TC_manual': -1,
            'TC_automated': -1,
            'TC_automateable': -1,
            'TC_3rd': -1,
            'Ratio': -1
        }
        self.empty_spaces = list(range(len(self.header_names)))

    def load_header_order(self):
        for header in self.header_names:
            for index, letter in enumerate(string.ascii_uppercase[:7]):
                if header == self.ws[f'{letter}1'].value:
                    self.header_order[header] = index
                    self.empty_spaces.remove(index)
                    break

        for key, value in self.header_order.items():
            if value == -1:
                self.insert_missing_header(key)

    def insert_missing_header(self, header):
        logging.info(f'There is missing header {header}')
        logging.info(f'Insert in progress')
        self.table.tableColumns[self.empty_spaces[0]].name = f'{header}'
        self.ws[f'{chr(65+self.empty_spaces[0])}1'].value = f'{header}'
        logging.info(f'Header {header} was inserted into {chr(65+self.empty_spaces[0])}1')
        self.empty_spaces.__delitem__(0)

    def check_wb(self):
        return 'Preview' in self.wb.sheetnames

    def load_project_list(self):
        self.ws = self.wb['Preview']
        self.table = self.ws.tables['Project_list']
        self.load_header_order()

    def exit(self):
        self.wb.save(self.path)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    tca = TCA()

    if not tca.check_wb():
        messagebox.showerror('Crucial error!', 'There is no sheet named "Preview"!\n'
                                               'Due to this exception script cannot proceed!\n'
                                               'If you renamed the sheet please rename it back...')
        exit(-1)

    tca.load_project_list()
    tca.exit()
```